# Paramiko Download, process and re-upload the same file

Tags: python, sftp, paramiko

I am using Paramiko to create an SFTP client to create a backup copy of a JSON file, read in the contents of the original, then update (the original).  I am able to get this snippet of code to work:

```
# open sftp connection stuff

# read in json create backup copy - but have to 'open' twice
read_file = sftp_client.open(file_path)
settings = json.load(read_file)
read_file = sftp_client.open(file_path)  
sftp_client.putfo(read_file, backup_path)

# json stuff and updating
new_settings = json.dumps(settings, indent=4, sort_keys = True)

# update remote json file
with sftp_client.open(file_path, 'w') as f:
    f.write(new_settings)
```

However when I try to clean up the code and combine the backup file creation and JSON load:

```
with sftp_client.open(file_path) as f:
    sftp_client.putfo(f, backup_path)    
    settings = json.load(f)
```

The backup file will be created but `json.load` will fail to due not having any content.  And if I reverse the order, the `json.load` will read in the values, but the backup copy will be empty.

I'm using Python 2.7 on a Windows machine, creating a remote connection to a QNX (Linux) machine.  Appreciate any help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to read the file second time, you have to seek file read pointer back to the file beginning:

```
with sftp_client.open(file_path) as f:
    sftp_client.putfo(f, backup_path)    
    f.seek(0, 0)
    settings = json.load(f)
```

Though that is functionally equivalent to your original code with two `open`'s.

---

If you aim was to optimize the code, to avoid downloading the file twice, you will have to read/cache the file to memory and then upload and load the contents from the cache.

```
f = BytesIO()
sftp_client.getfo(file_path, f)
f.seek(0, 0)
sftp_client.putfo(f, backup_path)    
f.seek(0, 0)
settings = json.load(f)
```

Comment: f.seek worked like a charm!  Thanks a bunch Martin; reading up on file.seek to educate myself.